# Pyspark joining of two dataframes results with error of duplicated values

Tags: join, pyspark

I have a problem in pyspark when joining two dataframes. The first dataframe is a one single column dataframe "zipcd", and the second one is a dataframe with four columns.

The problem arises whenever I try to join the two dataframes because Pyspark returns me in my new dataframe, regarding the one single column of zipcd, a column that all its value are the same (the first row is duplicated in all rows, and it is not like this).

For instance:

```
Zip.select("Zip").show()
+------------+
|         Zip|
+------------+
| 6.0651002E8|
| 6.0623002E8|
| 6.0077203E8|
| 6.0626528E8|
| 6.0077338E8|
|         0.0|
```

and the other dataframe is zipcd:

```
zip_cd1.show()
+-----+
|zipcd|
+-----+
|60651|
|60623|
|60077|
|60626|
|60077|
|    0|
```

Whenever I try to join the dataframes, it always happens the following:

```
Zip1=zip_cd1.join(Zip).select('Zip','zipcd')
Zip1.show()
+------------+-----+
|         Zip|zipcd|
+------------+-----+
| 6.0651002E8|60651|
| 6.0623002E8|60651|
| 6.0077203E8|60651|
| 6.0626528E8|60651|
| 6.0077338E8|60651|
|         0.0|60651|
```

It happens no matter if I change the type of join, and I don't have any idea of what's happening.

Expected output:

```
+------------+-----+
|         Zip|zipcd|
+------------+-----+
| 6.0651002E8|60651|
| 6.0623002E8|60623|
| 6.0077203E8|60077|
| 6.0626528E8|60626|
| 6.0077338E8|60077|
|         0.0|0    |
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: I will update my question

Comment: Give the keys for your join other wise it will be Cartesian join no matter what join you use.

Comment: there is no available keys because one of the dataframes only has a column (a single column dataframe)

Answer (score 1):

If both dataframes have the same number of partitions and the same number of rows you can use [RDD.zip](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.RDD.zip.html) and then re-create a dataframe from the result:

```python
zipped_rdd = zip.rdd.zip(zipcd.rdd).map(lambda x: (x[0]['Zip'], x[1]['zipcd']))
df = spark.createDataFrame(zipped_rdd, schema=['Zip', 'zipcd'])
```

If the dataframes have different numbers of partitions or rows, [RDD.zipWithIndex](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.RDD.zipWithIndex.html) and then a [full outer join](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.RDD.fullOuterJoin.html) can be used instead if the `zip`:

```python
zipped_rdd = zip.rdd.zipWithIndex().map(lambda x: (x[1], x[0])).fullOuterJoin(
  zipcd.rdd.zipWithIndex().map(lambda x: (x[1], x[0])) 
).map(lambda x: (x[1][0]['Zip'] if x[1][0] != None else None, x[1][1]['zipcd'] if x[1][1] != None else None))
df = spark.createDataFrame(zipped_rdd, schema=['Zip', 'zipcd'])
```

Result:

```
+-----------+-----+
|        Zip|zipcd|
+-----------+-----+
|6.0651002E8|60651|
|6.0623002E8|60623|
|6.0077203E8|60077|
|6.0626528E8|60626|
|6.0077338E8|60077|
|        0.0|    0|
+-----------+-----+
```

Comment: How did that worked out for you? I tried that code and it returned me that can only zip with rdds with same number of partitions (the first rdd zip had 200 partitions and the second one only 1). I repartitioned to only 1 partition the first rdd and then it returned me with the error 'Can only zip RDDs with same number of elements in each partition' How did you do that avoiding those errors?

Comment: @ArnoldoOliva The test data looked to me like both dataframes were very similar. I have added a possible solution for a more general case.

Answer (score 1):

I understood the data in a way that zip code 60651 is stored as 6.0651002E8 , With that assumption I have given the solution below.

```
    >>> df = spark.read.text('test.dat')
    >>> df.show()
    +-----------+
    |      value|
    +-----------+
    |6.0651002E8|
    |6.0623002E8|
    |6.0077203E8|
    |6.0626528E8|
    |6.0077338E8|
    |        0.0|
    +-----------+
    df.createOrReplaceTempView("Tempview")
    df = spark.sql("select substring(cast(cast(value as decimal) as string),1,5) zipcd,value as zip from TempView")
    +-----+-----------+
    |zipcd|        zip|
    +-----+-----------+
    |60651|6.0651002E8|
    |60623|6.0623002E8|
    |60077|6.0077203E8|
    |60626|6.0626528E8|
    |60077|6.0077338E8|
    |    0|        0.0|
    +-----+-----------+
    import pyspark.sql.functions as f
    from pyspark.sql.functions import *
    from pyspark.sql.types import *
    
    data = [
    ("60651","State1","County1"),
    ("60623","State2","County2"),
    ("60077","State2","County3"),
    ("60626","State2","County4"),
    ("60077","State2","County5"),
    ("0","Unkown","Unkown")
            ]
    
    schema = StructType([
    StructField('zip', StringType(),True),\
    StructField('state', StringType(),True),\
    StructField('county', StringType(),True),\
    ])
    df1 = spark.createDataFrame(data=data, schema=schema)
    df1.show()
    df.createOrReplaceTempView("Data")
    df1.createOrReplaceTempView("Data1")
>>> spark.sql("select * from Data1 A inner join Data B on A.zip=b.zipcd").show()
+-----+------+-------+-----+-----------+
|  zip| state| county|zipcd|        zip|
+-----+------+-------+-----+-----------+
|60651|State1|County1|60651|6.0651002E8|
|60623|State2|County2|60623|6.0623002E8|
|60077|State2|County3|60077|6.0077338E8|
|60077|State2|County3|60077|6.0077203E8|
|60626|State2|County4|60626|6.0626528E8|
|60077|State2|County5|60077|6.0077338E8|
|60077|State2|County5|60077|6.0077203E8|
|    0|Unkown| Unkown|    0|        0.0|
+-----+------+-------+-----+-----------+
```